# Is it safe to parge historic interior brick basement wall with hydrulic cement at grade?

Tags: basement, waterproofing, brick, old-house, mortar

I have a historic house from 1906 with soft bricks that had water leaking through top of basement wall near ground/grade level.  Opening up the basement ceiling I can see that the mortar is all gone, lots of dirt in the ceiling cavity and there are some gaps in the brick.

I'm working to remedy the water infiltration in the floor above the spot, but also wanted to seal up the wall as well from the inside.

Can we just parge that section of interior brick wall near the basement ceiling with hydraulic cement, or will that damage the brick because it's not the soft mortar that old bricks need with their expansion?

Or do I need the special historic mortar mix to not have the brick damaged?

Comment: 'Historic' as in 'protected/listed building' or just 'a century old'?

Comment: historic as in protected/landmark/listed

Comment: Then I would ask whoever is responsible for its listing before anyone else. I live in a protected area & even though my own house isn't itself listed/protected, we still have to get planning permission every time we breathe: materials, looks, they care about everything & if you do it wrong they make you tear it down & do it again :\